# Controlling Table display from another view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to display a table on the home view with 10 potential cells.

I need to press a button, go to the next view and select which cells I want to use via switches.

For example, if the switch is *on*, the cell is displayed. If the switch is *off* the cell will not be displayed and there will not be a gap between displayed cells on the previous page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to review [these guidelines for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure you get responses to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Uses the switches to control the data source for your UITableView, the best way to do this would be to break out your UITableViewDataSource into a separate class and then you can modify the data source array from your second view controller. I think [this tutorial](https://matteomanferdini.com/the-correct-way-to-display-lists-in-ios-and-what-many-developers-do-wrong/) would be a good starting point